# ssh with gpg-agent forwarding fails with "remote port forwarding failed for listen path"

Tags: ssh, gpg, macos, gpg-agent

SSH to remote machine using `gpg-agent` forwarding fails, but works with other machines. I cannot further ssh from remote machine using my local `gpg-agent` credentials.

`ssh -Avvv user@remotehost` shows this warning:

```
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen path /Users/user/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent
```

After connecting to a remote host I cannot see any valid available ssh keys:

```
% ssh-add -L
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered that situation when working remotely on my macOS but that is also true for any other OS that you want to `ssh -A` to with `gpg-agent` forwarding!

1. Make sure you have correct `~/.ssh/config` on your `<local_host>` that you connect to remote host from. Also make sure you are using this `<remote_hostname>` or IP when connecting from your `<local_host>` with `ssh -A <remote_username>@<remote_hostname_or_ip>`. Note that **macOS uses `/Users/username`** home directory **not `/home/username`**!! Be vigilant when Copy-Paste existing configuration. Example below:

```
Host <remote_hostname_or_ip>
    HostName <remote_hostname_or_ip>
    User <remote_username>
    RemoteForward /Users/<remote_username>/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent /home/<local_host_username>`/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
```

2. Make sure your `<local_host>` `gpg-agent` configuration contains `enable-ssh-support` line and the `pinentry-program` is correct and operational (it should ask you for pin when using `ssh`), for instance:

```
enable-ssh-support
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry
```

3. Make sure that your `<local_host>` `gpg-agent` is running. Try connecting to a known host that works. You can reload gpg-agent and it should return `OK` status:

```
% gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
OK
```

4. Make sure you are using `ssh -A` switch that is equivalent to `ForwardAgent yes` in `~/.ssh/config` for a given remote host. Use second option if you always want to forward agent with no `-A` parameter.
5. **MOST IMPORTANT:** Make sure that **remote host does NOT have `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` set** otherwise your local `gpg-agent` will not be forwarded to a remote machine and it will not use your local credentials! You can `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` if you set that variable by hand. If your remote host shell `~/.profile` (or similar) spawns `gpg-agent` and sets `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` it will also override your localhost agent socket and it will not work - comment that out:

```
#/usr/local/bin/gpg-agent --daemon
#SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out **5**.

Answer (score 1):

On my Fedora 34 laptop connecting to a Fedora 34 server, I was getting the "remote port forwarding failed for listen path" warning.

What worked for me is deleting the specified file, exiting the ssh session, and connecting again...

```
❯ gpg-agent --daemon
❯ ssh myserver
Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen path /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
[me@myserver] $ rm /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
[me@myserver] $ exit
❯ ssh myserver
[me@myserver] $ gpg-agent # Verify that gpg-agent is working
gpg-agent[159856]: gpg-agent running and available
```

I had to do that every time.

I then tried adding `StreamLocalBindUnlink yes` to the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file as recommended here: https://wiki.gnupg.org/AgentForwarding

After that, I never had the warning message again.